# Committing to a new SVN server

Tags: svn

My old svn repo is no longer accessible, the physical server no longer exists. So, I'm going to be making a new one. I still have all the actual data plus newly modified and added files since. I'm wondering if it's possible to just commit all the files to the new repo. Or will I have to remove all the .svn files, and begin anew?

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if you describe what do you mean by "svn repo died". What happened exactly? Don't you have a backup?

Comment: As @bahrep noted, not available does not mean automatically "repo died" - if physical access to repo storage exist in any from, repository *may be* restored and moved (if needed) into new location

Comment: @bahrep There is no backup, else I wouldn't be making this post. I rephrased the question to further clarify the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you checkout a subversion repository you don't fetch all the metadata. because Subversion is not distributed as Git for example. So I am afraid you lost your history, revision changes, etc.

So as you guessed you will need to remove the .svn metada and just create a new repo and commit everything again.

Comment: Sorry, but there are more convenient ways to "restore" the SVN repository and keep revision history. This answer will not help anyone in the future. Apache Subversion's first job is keeping data safe. To do that, the Subversion development community takes data safety and security very seriously.

Comment: @bahrep - "more convenient ways" exist **in the assumption** that the repo physically exist, which may not reflect the real situation

Comment: I can't read people mind but if he said "My old svn repo died, completely inaccessible" I take for granted that the server is gone and there is no backup. In that case that's the only way how to restore some of data. If there is anyone who can do something better with the local copy let me know.

Answer (score 1):

It would be much easier to help you if you describe what do you mean by "svn repo died". What happened exactly? Don't you have a backup? I've never encountered a case when repository is completely inaccessible (unless it is  FUBAR).

BTW if the issue is just about connectivity to Subversion server: if you still have access to the machine where your [repository](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html#svn.basic.repository) is stored you can always m[ove the repository to another server](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate).

Comment: I did not go further into it as I knew it wouldn't help. The physical svn server that I was using had been canceled without my knowledge (I was not the owner of it). So, the svn server no longer exists, the server contains no data.

Answer (score 1):

Paraphrase of @bahrep and @golja

If you have **only Working Copy** and **can't get accessin any form*** to repository data (high- or low-level) - you lost all your history.

Can't recall Subversion's behavior in this case, but you can at least to try (for "creating new repo" as last resort)

- Switch your WC to the URL of new empty repository (if name-change happened)
- Without removing .svn metadata from WC commit data in current state (which may fail, because you have REV N in repo and try to commit to repo with HEAD revision 0)